# как автоматически скрывать окно?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, tkinter

**Пытаюсь создать программу, и задумался как сделать авто скрытие.**

• Ведь у окна стоит атрибут `overrideredirect = True`, тогда окно скрывается пропадает с панели. Мне надо сделать при нажатие другой вкладки ( напр. ), скрывается окно и появляется на панели ( без кнопки ).

• В попытках ставил бинд на потерю фокуса, но работа была с миганием, дерганием и лагами.

• Код с биндами утерял, но могу написать шаблон ( как было, но без биндов ).

• Вот шаблон ( интерфейс программы ) :

```py
import tkinter


width # ширина экрана, посторонний модуль. ( переменная )
height # высота экрана, посторонний модуль. ( переменная ) 



root = tkinter.Tk()

root.attributes('-topmost', True)

root.geometry('{}x{}'.format(width, height - 40))

root.overrideredirect(1)



content = tkinter.Frame(root, cursor = '')

content ['background'] = '#2e2e2e'

content.pack_propagate(0)

content.pack(fill = tkinter.BOTH, expand = 1)



border = tkinter.Frame(content)

border ['background'] = '#90ee90'

border.place(x = 0, y = 0, width = width, height = 20)



button_exit = tkinter.Button(border, border = 0, command = lambda : sys.exit(), background = '#ff7f50', text = ' ', activebackground = '#ff7f50')

button_exit.place(x = width - 20, width = 20, height = 20)



root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для этого надо изменить `overrideredirect` на False, при ловле нужного события и тогда уж создать иконку на панели задач. При разворачивании окна надо ловить событие [`<Map>`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/bind.html) и возвращать `overrideredirect` на True.

> Map, Unmap
> The Map and Unmap events are generated whenever the mapping state of a window changes.
> Windows are created in the unmapped state. Top-level windows become mapped when they transition to the normal state, and are unmapped in the withdrawn and iconic states. Other windows become mapped when they are placed under control of a geometry manager (for example pack or grid).
>
> A window is viewable only if it and all of its ancestors are mapped.
> Note that geometry managers typically do not map their children until
> they have been mapped themselves, and unmap all children when they
> become unmapped; hence in Tk Map and Unmap events indicate whether or
> not a window is viewable.

Для образца сделал клик на салатовый фрейм, для сокрытия:

```
import tkinter
import sys

width = 400  # ширина экрана, посторонний модуль. ( переменная )
height = 400  # высота экрана, посторонний модуль. ( переменная )
flag = True


def show_ico(e):
    global flag
    flag = False
    root.withdraw()
    root.overrideredirect(flag)
    root.iconify()


def show_root(e):
    global flag
    flag = True
    root.overrideredirect(flag)
    root.deiconify()
    root.focus_force()


root = tkinter.Tk()
root.attributes('-topmost', True)
root.geometry('{}x{}+400+300'.format(width, height - 40))
root.overrideredirect(flag)
root.bind('<Map>', show_root)
root.bind('<FocusOut>', show_ico)

content = tkinter.Frame(root, cursor='')
content['background'] = '#2e2e2e'
content.pack_propagate(0)
content.pack(fill=tkinter.BOTH, expand=1)

border = tkinter.Frame(content)
border['background'] = '#90ee90'
border.place(x=0, y=0, width=width, height=20)
border.bind('<ButtonPress-1>', show_ico)

button_exit = tkinter.Button(border, border=0, command=lambda: sys.exit(), background='#ff7f50', text=' ',
                             activebackground='#ff7f50')
button_exit.place(x=width - 20, width=20, height=20)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: unmap, map это уже следствия на какие-то другие события, например клик на иконку.

Comment: Какое событие срабатывает на клик вне области ?

Comment: <FocusOut> добавил событие в код.